# Ruby dynamic symbol in each block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I make my symbol dynamic with an incremental number like this:

```
@order.products.each do |product,num|
    = f.input :aanbod+num.to_s
```

Comment: In this case, just use a `String`!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This form is equivalent to `"aanbod#{num}".to_sym` and more concise:

```
= f.input :"aanbod#{num}"
```

Comment: For a slightly different usage: `varname.to_sym` is more readable in my opinion than `:"#{varname}"`.  Nice to know both and use whichever better fits the case at hand

Comment: @StanKurdziel well the issue here is that the variable name is dynamic in this case so a simple `varname.to_sym` is not an option.

Answer (score 6):

```
= f.input ("aanbod" + num.to_s).to_sym
```

or

```
= f.input "aanbod#{num}".to_sym
```